# Servicestack serialization

Tags: c#, servicestack

For example I have this object

```
JsonObject o = new JsonObject();
o.Add("k1","0123");
o.Add("k2","123.");
```

When I serialize this json object the result is wrong:

```
{
 "k1":0123,"k2":123.
}
```

It assumes that, those are numbers. Whereas these are incorrect numbers.
We have problems deserializing them on client side.
The correct value should be like below:

```
{
"k1":"0123","k2":"123."
}
```

How can I achieve this? 
How to disable detecting numbers at all???

Below configurations did not help, I think they are for other purposes

```
JsConfig.TryToParseNumericType = false;
JsConfig.TryToParsePrimitiveTypeValues = false;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JsonObject](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/6fde44c35edc2344fc540561b760a5d528efe0fc/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsonObject.cs#L67) class derives from `Dictionary<string, string>` so I don't think there is much  you can do with that. You can create an instance of `Dictionary<string, object>` instead.

```
[Test]
public void SerializerTest()
{
    Dictionary<string, object> o = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    o.Add("k1", "0123");
    o.Add("k2", "123.");

    Assert.AreEqual("{\"k1\":\"0123\",\"k2\":\"123.\"}", 
                    JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(o));
}
```

Comment: @jaynakus I updated the example. Is it what you want?

Comment: Being rude to strangers trying to help you sure helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I made your way Ufuk

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use the JsonConvert class, which handles JSON really well.
Usage would be as follows:

```
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { k1 = "0123", k2 = "123" });
dynamic deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized);
Assert.That(deserialized.k1.ToString(), Is.EqualTo("0123")); // deserialized.k1 will be an object of 'JValue', so need to call toString()
```